# Does checkpoint block writes?

Tags: sql-server

This was kind of answered before, however this is a more specific question about the internals of the checkpoint process in SQL Server.

When a checkpoint is running and a data page is in the middle of being written to disk, what happens to a thread that is trying to obtain an exclusive latch on that page?

Answer (score 0):

What are latches..?

latches are lightweight synchronization objects used by SQL Server to protect shared data structures in memory,even for reading,writing

Check Point flushes all dirty pages to disk..

Your question is :

> what happens to a thread that is trying to obtain an exclusive latch on that page?

That won't be discarded to disk..

> SQL Server makes sure that pages are not read concurrently multiple times into the buffer pool, and that pages are not discarded from the buffer pool, when they are currently accessed by a query.

References:
http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/06/23/introduction-to-latches-in-sql-server/